# Database for storing passwords

Tags: database, database-design, passwords

I am planing to create a service to authenticate users by username and password.

I will salt and hash the password and I want to store the username, the salt and the hash in a database.

Now I am not sure which database I should use. I was thinking of a Key-Value database. What kind of database would make sense to store those information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty much any one will do, which means you should stick with the one you are most comfortable with.

Answer (score 1):

You can use mongodb database which is a key value database and is very fast in getting and updating  the data. You can easily store the username and hash the password in it and it is also very flexible.

Comment: it can be set at the time of insertion